# Project\taskApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879 in lavarel

Tags: php, laravel

Codes in controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Testcontrol extends Controller
{
    public function indexabout()
    {
        return view ('about');
    }
    public function indexcontact()
    {
        return view ('contact');
    }
}
```

Codes in Route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Testcontrol;




Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about','Testcontrol@indexabout');
Route::get('/contact','Testcontrol@indexcontact');
```

But Finally it shows the error
**Project\taskApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Testcontrol] does not exist.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a file path with a line number after it.

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Testcontrol] does not exist.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link, rather than comments, to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8+ you don't have default namespace for controllers so doing `'TestController@indexcontact'` won't work unless you set a namespace in `RouteServiceProvider`. But the standard way to do routing these days is to do it like this:

```
Route::get('/contact',[Testcontrol::class, 'indexcontact']);
```

and don't forget the use statement which you already have: `use App\Http\Controllers\Testcontrol;`

Release note for the change:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates